# LED not turning on in automatic pump shut off circuit (Proteus)

Tags: led, proteus, fluid-pump

I am unable to get the LED to turn on when the logic state (at 25%) is at 1 to shut off the pump.

[image]in

The Proteus simulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that U1VCC lane has blue indicator (D1's cathode, R1's top-end, and relay coil's top end) so the voltage may not have been set correctly. First make sure that U1VCC is 5 VDC.

As for the LED, you can see that the R4-D2 pair will see around 0.7VDC due to the transistor's BE junction. So it's not an enough voltage to turn the LED on.

You need to make two changes:
1- Move the R4's top-end connection from Q2's base to 555's output.
2- Decrease R4 to something meaningful. It's too much for the LED to light up. You can decrease the LED's nominal drive current (double click on the LED icon and decrease it's nominal drive current on the pop-up window) but in practice 10k will still be too high. So it's better to keep it low like up to 4.7k.